# Use wp_head hook on template page

Tags: php, hooks, core

I try to use the hook wp_head on a template page but this does not work

```
add_action('wp_head', 'to_head');

function to_head(){
    //do stuff
}
```

I placed this code on a template part what is called by `get_template_part( 'temp-parts/content/pages/catalog' );`

Can you use the hook only on the functions.php or is there a way to use this on any page

Comment: You can use the hook in any templates as long as the function or hook named `wp_head` has not yet been called - in templates other than `header.php`, your code would be placed before `get_header()`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sally CJ noted in a comment, if you're adding the `add_action()`, which targets `wp_head` in a partial file, you add with `get_template_part()` then you're late as the action has already fired.

You need to use `add_action()` in your `functions.php` file to register your callback before the target action is fired. If you need to add the callback only on certain context, then use the [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to check what is the current template / content.

```
// Do something on every template/view
add_action('wp_head', 'my_global_head_function');

add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect_callback');
function my_template_redirect_callback() {
    // Only pages
    if ( is_page() ) {
        add_action('wp_head', 'my_page_head_function');
    }
}

function my_global_head_function() {
    echo 'This works everywhere';
}

function my_page_head_function() {
    echo 'This is a page';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create a **function**, [**add**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) the action then [**do**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) the action?

```
function code_name() {
    // add code here
}
add_action( 'action_name', 'code_name' );
```

Then inside your template file, simply paste `<?php do_action( 'action_name' ); ?>`

P.S. You may change the `action_name` and `code_name` to whatever you like!